# How can I get the right product name and price?

Tags: php, mysqli

**DB Tables::**

**sales- salesID || price || date**
SS011 || 321.00 || 2018-08-18

SS012 || 5422.5 || 2018-09-06

SS013 || 4563.00 || 2018-10-12

SS014 || 3212.00 || 2018-11-14

SS015 || 231.00 || 2018-12-16

**salesinfo - salesID || quantity || productCode**

SS011 || 52 || 1

SS012 || 258 || 2

SS013 || 12 || 3

SS014 || 12 || 3

SS015 || 25 || 1

**product - productCode || productName || productPrice**

1 || Nippon White Paintings || 38.00

2 || Roof ||48.00

3 || Hammer || 28.00

**Expected Outcome::**

**Product Name || Date || Quantity || Unit Price (RM) || Total Price (RM)**

Nippon White Paintings  2018-12-16  25  38.00   231.00

Roof    2018-11-14  12  48.00   3212.00

Hammer  2018-10-12  12  28.00   4563.00

Hammer  2018-09-26  258 28.00   5422.50

Nippon White Paintings  2018-08-18  52  38.00   321.00

**Here is my code::**

```
SELECT sales.salesID, sales.price, sales.date, salesinfo.quantity, 
product.productName, product.productPrice
FROM sales
JOIN salesinfo ON sales.salesID = salesinfo.salesID                             
JOIN product ON salesinfo.productCode = salesinfo.productCode
GROUP BY salesinfo.salesID                                      
ORDER BY sales.date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**Actual Result Come Out::**

**Product Name || Date || Quantity || Unit Price (RM) || Total Price (RM)**

Nippon White Paintings  2018-12-16  25  38.00   231.00

Nippon White Paintings  2018-11-14  12  38.00   3212.00

Nippon White Paintings  2018-10-12  12  38.00   4563.00

Nippon White Paintings  2018-09-26  258 38.00   5422.50

Nippon White Paintings  2018-08-18  52  38.00   321.00

The product name and unit price have been repeat. Should I Group the salesinfo.salesID and join with product table?

Comment: I can't really help you, because you never even showed what your expected output looks like.  Please add sample data for all tables, and then add the output you expect.  Note that there probably isn't anything wrong with your query; it's doing what it should, just not what you want.

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen
Thanks for reply. I have edit my question and add my database table. The result come out for the productName and productPrice were not same with the data with the productCode in salesinfo table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOIN product ON salesinfo.productCode = salesinfo.productCode
```

This code above is from your query. This is totally useless as you compare both `productCode` from the same table. Change it to this code.

```
JOIN product ON salesinfo.productCode = product.productCode
```

Also, you don't need to `GROUP BY` to get desired result.

Comment: It it works, considers accepting my answer. It will help others who have similar problem in the future.